# How can I redirect in the quick_view page after deleting feedback?

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

My motive is that I want to redirect `quick_view.html` after deleting particular feedback on a particular product. How can I do it?

***views.py:***

```
def quick_view(request, quick_view_id):
    
    quick_view = get_object_or_404(Products, pk=quick_view_id)

    context = {
        "quick_view":quick_view,
    }
        
    return render(request, 'quickVIEW_item.html', context)

def feedBack(request,quick_view_id):
    quick_view = get_object_or_404(Products, pk=quick_view_id)
    if request.method == "POST" and request.user.is_authenticated:

        try:
            ProductREVIEWS.objects.create(
                user=request.user,
                product=quick_view,
                feedBACK=request.POST.get('feedBACK'),
            )
            return redirect('quick_view', quick_view_id)
        except:
            return redirect('quick_view', quick_view_id)

    else:
        return redirect('quick_view', quick_view_id)
```

**After deleting the particular feedback, I want to redirect to the quick_view page of that particular product. Now shows below error:**

```
def DeleteFeedback(request,id,quick_view_id):
    
    ProductREVIEWS.objects.get(pk=id).delete()
    messages.success(request,"Successfully your feedback deleted.")
    return redirect('quick_view', quick_view_id)
```

***urls.py:***

```
    path('quick_view/<int:quick_view_id>/', views.quick_view, name="quick_view"),
    path("feedBack/<int:quick_view_id>/", views.feedBack, name="feedBack"),
    path("DeleteFeedback/<int:id>/", views.DeleteFeedback, name="DeleteFeedback")
```

***error:***

```
TypeError at /DeleteFeedback/22/
DeleteFeedback() missing 1 required positional argument: 'quick_view_id'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/DeleteFeedback/22/
Django Version: 4.0.4
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
DeleteFeedback() missing 1 required positional argument: 'quick_view_id'
Exception Location: D:\1_WebDevelopment\17_Ecomerce Website\ecomerce site\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 197, in _get_response
Python Executable:  D:\1_WebDevelopment\17_Ecomerce Website\ecomerce site\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.5
Python Path:    
['D:\\1_WebDevelopment\\17_Ecomerce Website\\ecomerce site',
 'c:\\users\\dcl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\python39.zip',
 'c:\\users\\dcl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\DLLs',
 'c:\\users\\dcl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib',
 'c:\\users\\dcl\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39',
 'D:\\1_WebDevelopment\\17_Ecomerce Website\\ecomerce site\\env',
 'D:\\1_WebDevelopment\\17_Ecomerce Website\\ecomerce '
 'site\\env\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 16 Jul 2022 05:49:50 +0000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I solved it and shared it, so that people can be benefited...***

```
   def DeleteFeedback(request,id):
    
        feedback = ProductREVIEWS.objects.get(pk=id)
        product_id = feedback.product.id
    
        feedback.delete()
        messages.success(request,"Successfully your feedback deleted.")
        return redirect(reverse('quick_view', args=[product_id]))
```

***Note:***
here product = field of a feedback model

```
class ProductREVIEWS(models.Model):

    product = models.ForeignKey(Products, related_name='productREVIEWrelatedNAME',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    feedBACK = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```